# How to get address from private key in java

Tags: accounts, addresses, private-key, ethereumj

I use generate a private key in java code `HashUtil.sha3("cow".getBytes())`

Write to a new private key file:

```
c85ef7d79691fe79573b1a7064c19c1a9819ebdbd1faaab1a8ec92344438aaf4
```

Then, I use `geth account import`, I got an address `["0xcd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826"]` in geth.

But when I try to get public address in Java, it shows a different address:

> ```
> BigInteger pk = new BigInteger(senderPrivKey);
> ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(pk);
> System.out.println("address\t: " + Hex.toHexString(key.getAddress()) );
> ```

The result is `address  : 8e54de809503da0a87309f8d5e98f77551ddd7f5`

I expected the address to show `cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826`, did I use wrong code?

I also learned the [ECKeyTest.java](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/develop/ethereumj-core/src/test/java/org/ethereum/crypto/ECKeyTest.java) in EthereumJ, there are unit tests that gets public key from private key first, and then get address from public key. But in my case, the result is still `8e54de809503da0a87309f8d5e98f77551ddd7f5`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in this code, `byte[] senderPrivKey = HashUtil.sha3("cow".getBytes());`, and Hex.encode(senderPrivKey) equals "c85ef7d79691fe79573b1a7064c19c1a9819ebdbd1faaab1a8ec92344438aaf4"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Summary

The code in the question theoretically should not run, as the private key is in hex format and the call to `new BigInteger(senderPrivKey)` to parse the hex string without the `16` radix specified would result in a thrown exception.

When the code is adjusted to use `new BigInteger(senderPrivKey, 16)` specifying the base 16 radix, the public key is generated as expected.

---

## The Details

Here is a working example. Save it as TestKey.java, compile and run it.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.ethereum.crypto.ECKey;
import org.spongycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class TestKey {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String senderPrivKey = "c85ef7d79691fe79573b1a7064c19c1a9819ebdbd1faaab1a8ec92344438aaf4";

        BigInteger pk = new BigInteger(senderPrivKey, 16);
        System.out.println("Private key: " + pk.toString(16));

        ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(pk);
        System.out.println("Public key: " + Hex.toHexString(key.getAddress()));
    }
}
```

And the output when running it:

```
Private key: c85ef7d79691fe79573b1a7064c19c1a9819ebdbd1faaab1a8ec92344438aaf4
Public key: cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826
```

I have used the following maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ethereum</groupId>
        <artifactId>ethereumj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-RELEASE</version>
        <!--  <type>zip</type>  -->
    </dependency>
```

I don't know how your code ran, because when I change the following line in the source code above to match your code, the `BigInteger(...)` constructor is expecting to parse a base 10 number rather than a base 16 number :

```
        BigInteger pk = new BigInteger(senderPrivKey);
```

And I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:461)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:597)
    at TestKey.main(TestKey.java:14)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! I add a code in question's comment, that in my code, `byte[] senderPrivKey = HashUtil.sha3("cow".getBytes());`, senderPrivKey is not a String, and `Hex.encode(senderPrivKey)` is `"c85ef7d79691fe79573b1a7064c19c1a9819ebdbd1faaab1a8ec92344438aaf4"`

Comment: Did the updated version change something? I am not able to generate the address!